# Android DatePicker avoid highlights on current date (today)

Tags: java, android, xml, styles, android-datepicker

I have a DatePicker in my Android app and I disabled some dates (as shown in below picture).

[image]

Here I disabled all the dates after December 7 and **today date is December 9**.

As you can see December 9 (i.e. today) is highlighted with the App's accent color (dark blue), even though that date is disabled.

How can I disable that highlight, so that present date also looks similar to other disabled date (something like grayed out).

I used android.app.DatePickerDialog and set the max date using its setMaxDate() function.

In styles.xml I haven't added any styles for the DatePicker so far, as I am okay with App's default styling.

Thanks for reading and please let me know, if more details required. Hope to see your support.